# How to force invokation of a method after creating an instance

Tags: java, methods

I made a small program with some methods and underlying classes with it in Java. Some other person (lets assume random and don't know my code) wants to use it. So it creates a new instance of the class I made. My class uses some sockets (both serversocket and normal socket) and those needs to be closed (as I read, leaving them to garbage collection is a bad thing to do). Now I made a method that takes care of all the closing, but I need to "force" the user somehow to invoke that method at some point in the future too. Is this possible?

Closest what I got was to use the finalizer of the class to close all the connections. Though this is a bad idea since the class may be alive the whole program so this method may never be called.

Comment: Dont ever use the finaliser. It's not reliable that it will even be called, and you cant control when GC happens in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, finalizers aren't the right approach for this. Instead, implement [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) on the class and ensure the documentation makes clear that instances must be closed when the code is done with the instance. `AutoCloseable` makes it compatible with the [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which makes it easy for consumers of your class to close it correctly. This is what the various JDK classes that need to do cleanup do (for instance, [`FileWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)).

Comment: Thanks, let me look into that. To some extend I find it weird that this feature is not supported.

Comment: @user3892683: It is -- by try-with-resources and `AutoCloseable`. :-) (And yes, before we had them, it was a big pain. Had to write convoluted `try-finally` blocks with nested `try-catch` blocks in them...blech.)